# OCUnit on private properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, tdd, ocunit

I am new to test driven development and have a basic question. How do I access private properties for unit testing? There are plenty of answers on how you access methods but I couldn't find much on properties. Here is what I've got now for my class CDTest. Excluding some of the imported headers for readability purposes.

CDTest.h

```
@interface CDTest : NSObject

@end
```

CDTest.m

```
#import "CDTest.h"
#import "CDTest+Protected.h"

@interface CDTest()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@end

@implementation CDTest

- (void)setup
{
    //Sets up the context
}

@end
```

CDTest+Protected.h

```
@interface CDTest()

- (void)setup;

@end
```

Unit test .m file

```
#import "CDTest.h"
#import "CDTest+Protected.h"

@implementation CDTestTests
{
    CDTest *cdTest;
}

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    cdTest = [CDTest new];
}

- (void)testSetup
{
    [cdTest setup];
    //Now I need access to the properties in cdTest to validate them
}

@end
```

Comment: Wanting a test to access a private property is a code smell. Try to test entirely through your public API. If you say, "But I really need this," listen to your test: another class is trying to get out. See http://qualitycoding.org/testability-vs-hiding/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C properties are methods (each property is a getter and a setter if it is read/write).

Just declare your property in your protected category, which should be declared something like this

```
@interface CDTest(Protected)

- (void)setup;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@end
```

Comment: Duh! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.